# Why EditText call notifyDataSetChanged() method?

Tags: java, android

I am dealing with a strange situation.
I implement a class that extend ArrayAdapter.
There is two view type, the first view is "classic" and the second has an EditText. Just one item can have the second type of view at the same time.
When the Edit text is focus and when the keyboard is open, my adapter reload constantly and stop after a while (not fix).
I don't think it is a bad use of the notifyDataSetChanged() method that i override :

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    Log.i("ADAPTER","reload");
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I don't get this log but in :

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) { 
    Log.i("ADAPTER","new view");
    //
    // some stuff
    //
    return convertView;
}
```

I got this log.
A video that show the problem :
[image]

```
public class LabelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Label> {

    private ConfigInterface ci;
    private DatabaseInterface di;
    private int itemSelected;

    public static int NORMAL = 0;
    public static int SELECTED = 1;

    public LabelAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, DatabaseInterface databaseInterface, ConfigInterface configInterface) {
        super(context, resource, configInterface.getLabels());
        this.di = databaseInterface;
        this.ci = configInterface;
        itemSelected = -1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final Label label = this.getItem(position);
        final int pos = position;
        Log.i("Test","tous");
        if (getItemViewType(position) == SELECTED){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_lv_label_edit, null);
            EditText et = convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_label_name); // it's this edit text
            et.setText(label.getName());
            et.requestFocus();
            Log.i("Test","select");
            ImageView check = convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            check.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check);
            ImageView del = convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            del.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
            return convertView;
        }
        else {
            Log.i("Test","no sel");
            convertView =    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_lv_label_item, null);
            TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.l_name);
            tv.setText(label.getName());
            ImageView iv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ic_label);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_label);
            iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Listen","label");
                }
            });
            try {
                int color = Color.parseColor(label.getColor());
                iv.setColorFilter(color);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            TextView n = convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            int n_ci = di.getCountDatabaseByLabel(label.getName());
            if (n_ci != 0) n.setText("" + n_ci);
            ImageView edit = convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            edit.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_edit);
            edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setSelectedItem(pos);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Listen","item");
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int posistion){
        itemSelected = posistion;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       if (position == itemSelected) return 1;
       else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        Log.i("Test","reload");
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the full code for your `Àdapter`

Comment: i don't remember exactly but i read somewhere that notifyDataSetChanged() is a final method.

Comment: and also you just need to call notifyDataSetChanged()..you don't need to override it

Comment: i override notifyDataSetChanged() just to add log and see if i use it badly. I added full code of My Adapter.